# Why can I see through a face when another is close?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, camera

When I have two faces that are close together I can see through face in front depending on the several factors.

The camera's zoom impacts this a lot. The farther zoomed out I am the worse this is.

Perspective/Orthographic impacts this. Orthographic reducing the problem but not fixing it.

The angle I view this from impacts it. Head on being the worst and 90 degrees being the best.

How can I minimize this issue?

Example:

Zoomed out
[image: UV Sphere behind mesh]

Zoomed in
[image: Zooming in gives this]

EDIT: This appears in both edit mode and object mode but is much more prevalent in edit mode.

Comment: change the clip distance

Comment: Is this not also related to a subsurf modifier introducing surface intersections?